# Auto-renewable subscription for multi-user App

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, in-app-purchase

I'm offering tiered auto-renew subscriptions, where the pricing goes as follow:

- PLAN A : 1 Vault = $4/month
- PLAN B : 2 Vaults = $9/month
- PLAN C : 3 Vaults = $14/month
- PLAN D : 4 Vaults = $20/month

A user can decide to create 2 Accounts with us (Account X with 2 Vaults, and Account Y with 2 Vaults), and want to use the same iOS device and Apple ID for the purchase. They basically login using either Account X or Account Y in the App, only one at a time.

Does In-app Purchase allow for multiple auto-renew purchases of the same plan (PLAN B in this example) using the same Apple Id? I am managing the expiration dates for each Account (X & Y) using receipt validation, but I cannot confirm whether IAP treated them as separate purchases in the sandbox or single.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have the same iTunes account subscribed to two of the same products at the same time. You cannot have one iTunes account subscribed to two products in the same subscription group either.

Also, you must be careful to not associate renewal transactions with the wrong accounts. If user X is logged in when user Y's subscription renews, you will most likely give the renewal to user X. There is currently no way to associate in-app purchase with the application account that created them.

Comment: I'll check the transaction id with the user that logged in on API.
but if the user has another device on the same icloud I'll have the same problem??

Comment: Yep, you will. Subscriptions will be synced across devices that are using the same iTunes/iCloud account for the app store.